# jQuery validation: Add additional task to submit

Tags: jquery, validation

Can't figure this one out. I have the jquery validation plugin successfully validating all form inputs when submit is clicked. But... when submit is clicked, I also want to clear out the data on any inputs containing invalid text. Invalid inputs are assigned the class ".incomplete"

```
    $('#button').click(function(){
            var e = $('.incomplete').length;
            if (e) {
                $('.incomplete').val('');
            };
        });
```

The above code makes the "Submit" button clear invalid inputs the second time it is clicked. I don't see what I am doing that would make it execute on the second click rather than the first.

Full form, for those curious: http://pastie.org/4704511

Comment: I've also run this function under jquery validation's "invalidHandler" with the exact same result.

Comment: Have you tried using the "submit" callback for your form, instead of the button click?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've reduced it to the following and still need a second click `$('form').submit(function(){
    $('.incomplete').val('');
   });`

Comment: Try adding a trigger clicking the "submit" button when you end your "onsubmit" callback. Something like...
`$('form').submit(function(){ /* your code */ $(this).find(":submit").trigger("click"). });` But this is really strange to do... I've only do similar things for Internet Explorer, as it have a lot of problems with form callbacks like onsubmit.